# Why Fire + Smoke simulation doesn't work?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

And yes, I saw another post asking this, but the OP answered his own question and the explanation is beyond my understanding. Trust me, I don't like going here every time I found difficulty.

So I am using 2.9, and I followed Blender Guru's first beginner tutorial, and I couldn't seem to make the Fire + Smoke simulation. I selected the monkey, chose flow type >> Fire + Smoke, and it's just smoke, with no fire. Any advice?

Comment: Please attach your blend file so we can see what your simulation settings are.